# Cakephp LImiting Pagination Counter

Tags: cakephp

I want to limit the counter that is visible in pagination in cakephp? What should I do...? Currently its default showing as 1-9 as pages link. I tried limit but as it limits my post per page. I want to limit the counter not post per page. Please help me.

Modified... 
I tried modulus according to answers..

I want my Pagination should be this way. If it is on first Page then.

```
1 2 3 ... Last
```

If it is on Middle of page then..

```
First ... 6 7 8 ... Last
```

If it it on last then.

```
First ... 11 12 13
```

My tried code is.

```
<?php echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('modulus' => '2', 'tag' => 'span','first'=>'First','ellipsis'=>'...', 'separator' => ' ', 'last'=>'Last' )); ?>
```

Answer (score 5):

Check out the documentation for the pagination helper: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/paginator.html

I think want you want is "modulus - how many numbers to include on either side of the current page, defaults to 8."

So in your View, you'd have something like:

```
// Limit numbers to 4 either side of current page
echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('modulus' => 4));
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks buddy, I am highly obliged with your help... Hope to join you on bohra.sankalp at gmail.com

Comment: It's probably possible to do it the way you described, but it's not the way CakePHP is built to work out of the box, and it's not something I know how to do off-hand, sorry.